# Правильное структурирование проекта на C++ (Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, git, github, gitlab

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно принято структурировать проект на C++? Пользуюсь встроенным расширением GitHub в Visual Studio, он загружает код(заголовочные файлы и реализацию), файлы запуска .sln и остальные промежуточные файлы студии. Но мне нужно разбить проект отдельно на код, exeшник и документацию(соответственно по разным папкам), обходя лишние файлы студии(если это правильно). Как правильно реорганизовать рабочее пространство проекта? Я пытаюсь создать другие папки в самой студии - физически они не появляются(так как там только фильтра), пытаюсь создать физически отдельно - студия их не воспринимает и не видит. 
Подскажите, как правильно решить эту проблему и загрузить на github? При этом при использовании git clone чтобы клонировался проект, который можно сразу запустить. Не нашел подходящую информацию нигде. Спасибо!

Comment: "Котлеты - отдельно, мухи - отдельно" конфигурации проекта в одну директорию, код проекта в другую. Бинари на гит не кладут) ну а хедера и исходники раскладывайте как Вам удобно.

Comment: В Solution Explorer есть тумблер переключения вида фильтров / реальной структуры папок. *"git clone чтобы клонировался проект, который можно сразу запустить"* - оно так работать не должно, при клонировании получаются только исходники которые затем предстоит собрать.

Answer (score -3):

Как и в других языках, в C++ устоялись свои негласные правила структурирования проекта. Обычно простейшая структура выглядит примерно так:

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── app
│   └── main.cpp
├── include
│   ├── example.h
│   └── exampleConfig.h.in
├── src
│   └── example.cpp
└── tests
    ├── dummy.cpp
    └── main.cpp
```

То есть ваши тесты, документацию, заголовочники и исходники вы разбрасываете по разным папкам. Также обычно проект структурируют так, чтобы пользователь смог после `git clone` сделать `cd project_dir` и далее командой (которую вы конечно же оставите в README.md) скомпилировать ваш проект. Либо можно оставить скрипт `install.sh`, где вы вами уже укажете все нужные команды, которые просто нужно будет запустить. Документацию и примеры лучше всего также оставить в README.md, не забудьте также добавить лицензию в ваш проект. Обычно это файл LICENSE. 
Для добавления своих папок в проекты и прочих более гибких вещей советую использовать `git bash` (если я не ошибаюсь он называется так) - git-интерфейс для Windows, либо воспользоваться WSL с установленным git, и самим все добавить и запушить, а также сделать еще много других вещей, которые не позволяет сделать GUI MSVS.

Comment: в src - example а в app - main? что за наркомания?

Comment: @Andrey, очевидно, что app содержит `main()`, а src - весь остальной код. Иногда main.cpp выносят из папок вообще, иногда все собирают в одну папку. Я видел все вышеописанные случаи, так что если вам это кажется наркоманией, то советую посмотреть в репозитории на github каких-нибудь больших проектов, не думаю, что они занимаются "наркоманией"

Comment: @Andrey, как я сказал, что не помню точное название этой вещи, главное - я передал суть. Сам для таких вещей я пользуюсь WSL

Comment: @Andrey, я с вами спорить не буду, если вы не видели каких-то вещей, и где-то их нет, а как я выше описал, что бывают разные варианты, и вы считаете это "наркоманией" - ваше право

Comment: @Andrey, не понимаю,  причем тут ssh и "норм машины", когда речь идет о том, чтобы использовать git из-под линукса, поскольку GUI MSVS позволяет только жать кнопочки сильно упрощая интерфейс git'a, который доступен из консоли WSL